# unable Scrape text from website using scrappy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new here and I am trying to scrape the nearest station and distance list from this link https://www.onthemarket.com/details/10405122/ I have been stuck here for a day. any help would be apreciated.

I have tried

response.xpath('//div[@class = "tab-content"]/span')

response.xpath('//section//span[@class="poi-name"]')

response.xpath('//section[@class="poi"]/div//text()').extract()

nothing seems to work.

please if you are able to get it please do explain why I failed that would be much apreciated.

Comment: You want nth children so you have to use "//" instead "/" for example: `//div[@class = "tab-content"]//span`

Comment: Also don't forget to add get() and of the parser `response.xpath('//div[@class = "tab-content"]//span').get()` if it doesn't work again it is probably a js website. So you have to use selenium instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is not in the downloaded html:

```
<ol class="tab-list"></ol><div class="tab-content"></div>
```

It probably receives the data in another call. Try not hurry up writing the scraper, invest some time to understand how this particular UI works. I would also suggest downloading data via `curl` or `scrapy shell "your_url"` (as in this case it will not be downloaded by browser, which renders the page and can trick you like right now).

Comment: Thanks, I can't upvote you cause of some restrictions. I wish I could